# Создание библиотеки обобщенных функций для работы с массивами и списками на С#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Задача такая:
Реализовать статический класс и реализовать статические обобщенные методы, реализующие такую функциональность:

1. Обмен местами двух групп элементов
2. Обмен местами всех пар соседних элементов (с четным и нечетным индексом)
3. Вставка в массив (список) другого массива (списка) элементов в указанное место
4. Замена группы элементов другим массивом (список) элементов
5. Реализовать приведенные функции для массивов и списков.

Понял, что для этого задания стоит использовать IList. Реализовал свап елементов, но дальше, например Insert Element дается сложно, какие методы использовать для работы с IList, чтобе реализовать вышеперечисленные функции, чтобы они были применимы и для массивов, а не только для списков.

```
public static class ArrayListLib
{
    public static void SwapElem<TElem>(IList<TElem> arr, int i, int j)
    {
        TElem temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    public static void InsertElem<TElem>(IList<TElem> arr, int index, TElem elem)
    {
        int size = arr.Count;
        System.Array.Resize(ref arr, size);
        System.Array.Copy(arr, index, arr, index + 1, arr.Count - index - 1);
        arr[index] = elem;
    }
}
```

Вторую функцию по привычке начал писать с использованием Array class, но ожидаемо, оно не работает с  типом IList. Как быть?

Comment: Не спамьте пожалуйста версионными метками, выберите одну, а то не понятно, какой синтаксис вы ожидаете. Если устроит любая версия языка, можно вообще метку не указывать. От того что вы наспамили, быстрее ответ не получите.

Comment: Ответ был удален из-за длительного отсутствия реакции на него.